# Weird behavior of the input command in Scilab

Tags: input, scilab

I want my students to program a little game with Scilab like this one :

```
a=ceil(100*rand())
disp("I think of a number between 1 and 100. Which one ?")
guess=0
while(guess<>a) do
    guess= input("Guess :")
    if (a>guess) then
        disp("+")
    elseif (a<guess) then
        disp("-")
    end
end

disp("You got it")
```

But there are some weird behavior with the first inputs and the lasts. Just after the first input, sometimes I don't have an answer (but sometimes I do), I am asked "Guess" again, but this time with a usual prompt `-->` on the console. I can put anything, it doesn't seem to matter for the program. But the program is not over though, just after it returns to the expected behavior.

At the end, after the "You got it", there seems to be some inputs around. I got one or two prompts before I got the `-->` again.

Here is what the console may look like :

```
Guess :
50
Guess :
--> 50
Guess :
50



 +
Guess :
75


 -
Guess :
```

I can't figure out why Scilab react like this.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior in Scilab 5.5.1 - the program works normally for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced that a lot, and this is a known bug in `input()` of Scilab 6.0.0:

- http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15069
- http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14376
- http://bugzilla.scilab.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14424

The first link also presents a workaround, but I wouldn't say it is suitable for students. As @Desire couldn't reproduce that error, I recommend that you downgrade you Scilab to version 5.5.1, and also tell your students to do it too.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I believe the version I have at school is not 6.0.0. Probably even older that 5.5.1. I hope it will work fine then ;)